# Why is the my "max" value not accepted in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, max

Fiddling around with my graph, I don't succeed in convince Highcharts to stop the y-axis at the value of 5. It still continues to stop only at 6. [Here is the fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/wjq9b/1/). I set

```
 yAxis:
 { 
    max: 5
 }
```

But it's being ignored. Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `endOnTick:false` to the y-axis.

API for [**`endOnTick`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.endOnTick).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the function `setExtremes`

for example, inside the load event:

```
 // ...the setting object:

 // some settings...

chart:{
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        spacingBottom: 60,
        marginLeft: 50,
        marginTop: 70,
        events: {
                   load:function(event){                      
                                          var yAxis0=this.yAxis[0];
                                          yAxis0.setExtremes(0, 5 , true, true);
                                       }
                }
},

// other settings....
```

**the advantage in this approach is that you can change it dynamicly (and not just in the initiation stage)**